# findOne(predicate2).orElse(null) giving null during compilation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

error while compiling

```
TestUserManagerImpl.testGetUserByRefId:150 NullPointer
```

code line:-

```
when(getUserRepository().findOne(predicate2).orElse(null)).thenReturn(userBO);
```

recently upgrading my project and earlier it was working fine:-

```
when(getUserRepository().findOne(predicate2)).thenReturn(userBO);
```

any idea how can I avoid this error

Comment: Why did you add that `orElse(null)` in the first place?

Comment: if i don't add orelse then "The method thenReturn(Optional<UserBO>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Optional<UserBO>> is not applicable for the arguments (UserBO)" it tries to convert in optional which i don't want

Comment: Then pass `Optional.of(userBO)` to `thenReturn`. You're mocking `findOne`, which returns an `Optional`, not a `UserBO`.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you add `.orElse(null)`?

Removing it will most probably solve your problem.

If you have made this change due to the fact that you have made similar changes in your actual code (which you are trying to mock), then you do not necessarily need to add this in the mock statement as well (unless you are really trying to test for nullability, which I don't think is the case).

Comment: if i don't add orelse then "The method thenReturn(Optional<UserBO>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Optional<UserBO>> is not applicable for the arguments (UserBO)" it tries to convert in optional which i don't want

Comment: Did you try using ```.get()``` instead of ```.orElse(null)```? Can you also show the code that you are trying to mock?